# Why will java not let me use the method add() when creating a method?

Tags: java, eclipse

The error "The method `add(Shape)` in the type `ArrayList<Shape>` is not applicable for the arguments" shows up.

I want to add data from a file to an `ArrayList`. Shape is the name of the abstract class and the class I'm working in is the `Helper` class.

I apologize, I don't know much about coding.

```
public static ArrayList<Shape> create(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();

    String line = br.readLine();
    while(line != null){
        shapes.add();
        line = br.readLine();
    }

    br.close();
    return shapes;
}
```

Comment: You may want to tell it *what* to add.

Comment: You need to pass a `Shape` object to `shapes.add()`.

Comment: you would add a shape object to arrayList like shapes.add(shape). I believe your file contains some data which you're reading and you need to parse that data to create an object of shape

Comment: side note: consider to use try-with-resources to close the reader properly in a finally block.

Comment: The program accepts my data file, I just cannot seem to add it into an array list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

shapes is an `ArrayList` that takes `Shape` objects. When you call `shapes.add()` you need to supply the method with the object of type `Shape` to add to this list.

So I'm not sure how to construct a new `Shape` object I'm guessing it has something to do with what you are reading from this file. If `Shape` takes a `String` arg in the constructor...this is conjecture but...

```
public static ArrayList<Shape> create(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();

    String line = br.readLine();
    while(line != null){
        shapes.add(new Shape(line)); // create a new shape to add. 
        line = br.readLine();
    }

    br.close();
    return shapes;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Update based on your comment:

```
public static ArrayList<String> create(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    ArrayList<String> shapes = new ArrayList<>();

    String line = br.readLine();
    while(line != null){
        shapes.add(line); // add String
        line = br.readLine();
    }

    br.close();
    return shapes;
}
```

Comment: When I change the code to that, it tells me "Cannot instantiate the type Shape" the Shapes will be constructed by another method. This method is solely to add the Strings from a text file into an array list.

Comment: If that's the case then you don't need `Shape` here at all. You need an `ArrayList` that takes `String` types. I'll update the answer

Comment: +1 — I will add, @CorinneBerchtold, that when you declare your list you should make it `List<String> shapes = new ArrayList<>();` which is to say "I have a List of `<String>s` and I have chosen an _ArrayList_ as the List implementation."  None of your other code should ever care which _kind_ of List you use. Similarly, your `create` method should return `List<String>` like `public static List<String> create(String fileName)` … no other piece of code should care which sort of List is being created.